os.environ different between console and vscode
I'm trying to read system variables in my python script but for some reason it doesn't work in vscode.
I manually set the system variable MY_ENV_VAR to test through the system gui (windows).
Now, when running os.getenv('MY_ENV_VAR') in the console, I get the expected result of 'test', but when doing the same thing in vscode, I get None.
Both console and vscode use the exact same python interpreter.
After some digging, I found out that the in the console, os.environ is slightly different compared to the one I get in vscode, one of the differences being my newly created variable.
How can I set a system variable such that I can read in from within vscode?

You have to restart VSCode. Environment variable changes are only reflected in processes created after the change.
